# Who was St. Joseph's Father? The New Testament seems to give two answers

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-luke, textual-discrepancies, genealogy, joseph-husband-of-mary

[Matthew 1:16 (NASB)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%201:16&version=NASB)

> **16** Jacob was the father of Joseph the husband of Mary, by whom Jesus was born, who is called the Messiah.

[Luke 3:23 (ESV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%203:23&version=ESV)

> **23** Jesus, when he began his ministry, was about thirty years of age, being the son (as was supposed) of Joseph, the son of Heli,

The problem here is that Matthew names Jacob Jesus's Grandfather and Luke names Heli. What is going one here? A mistake? A misunderstanding of Jewish genealogies?

Answer (score 16):

The books of Matthew, Mark, Luke and John can be seen to present Christ as King, Servant, Man, and God (in that order). See E.W. Bullinger's wonderful book *Number in Scriptures* for more on this topic (the chapter on the number seven).

As Bullinger puts it, a king *must* have a genealogy, and a man *should* have one. You'll notice that Matthew's genealogy starts with Abraham and goes *down* to Joseph, while Luke's genealogy proceeds *up* from Joseph to Adam and God. Matthews lineage describes the *royal lineage* through Solomon, while Luke's lineage describes the *natural line* through Nathan (Solomon's older brother, the third of four sons to David and Bathsheba - see I Chronicles 3:5). The first (Matthew's) is *legal*, the latter (Luke's) is *natural*.

Both lines eventually meet when Joseph, the son of Jacob (Matthew) marries Mary, the daughter of Heli (Luke). Luke 3:23 refers to Joseph as being the son of Heli out of the Jewish legal sanction and customary practice to refer to the son-in-law as son.

To summarize, Matthew's is the genealogy of Joseph, son of Jacob. Luke's is the genealogy of Mary, daughter of Heli.

Source: [EW Bullinger's Number in Scriptures](http://philologos.org/__eb-nis/seven.htm)

Answer (score 15):

The genealogy in the gospel of Matthew is definitely the genealogy of Joseph, and the genealogy in Luke's Gospel is most likely that of Mary. This coincides with the primary audiences of the two books (Mathew the Jews, and Luke the Gentiles). Mathew would want to show according to Jewish tradition that Jesus was both a Jew and a Son of David. Luke was trying to show that Jesus was the promised redeemer that would crush the serpent's head for all of Adam's children.

For more information:

> ### [Clarke's Commentary on the Bible](http://bible.cc/luke/3-23.htm)
>
> That St. Luke does not always speak of sons properly such, is evident from the first and last person which he names: Jesus Christ was only the supposed son of Joseph, because Joseph was the husband of his mother Mary: and Adam, who is said to be the son of God, was such only by creation. After this observation it is next necessary to consider, that, in the genealogy described by St. Luke, there are two sons improperly such: i.e. two sons-in-law, instead of two sons. As the Hebrews never permitted women to enter into their genealogical tables, whenever a family happened to end with a daughter, instead of naming her in the genealogy, they inserted her husband, as the son of him who was, in reality, but his father-in-law.

Answer (score 0):

Eusebius (260-340 AD), who is called the father of church history, covers this topic in his classic work titled " **Ecclesiastical History" in book 1 chapter 7**:

> CHAPTER VII.
>
> **On the discrepancy which is supposed to exist in the Gospels 
>   respecting the genealogy of Christ.**
>
> As the genealogy of Christ is differently given to us by Matthew
>   and Luke, and they are supposed by the generality to disagree in
>   their statements ; and as every believer, for want of knowing the
>   truth, has been led to apply some investigation to explain  the
>   passages, we may also subjoin the account which has come  down to us.
>   We refer to the history which has been handea  down on these passages
>   by Africanus, in an epistle to Aristides,  respecting the harmony of
>   the genealogy of the gospels. After  having refuted the opinions of
>   others as forced and fictitious, he  sets forth the account that he
>   had ascertained himself, in the following words. " It was customary
>   in Israel to calculate the  names of the generations, either according
>   to nature, or accord  ing to the law; according to nature, by the
>   succession of legitimate  offspring ; according to the law, when
>   another raised children to  the name of a brother who had died
>   childless. For as the hope  of a resurrection was not yet clearly
>   given, they imitated the promise which was to take place by a kind
>   of mortal resurrection,  with a view to perpetuate the name of the
>   person who had died.  Since then, there are some of those who are
>   inserted in this gene-  alogical table, that succeed each other in the
>   natural order of  father and son, some again that were born of others,
>   and were as-  cribed to others by name, both the real and reputed
>   fathers have  been recorded. Thus, neither of the gospels has made a
>   false  statement, whether calculating in the order of nature, or
>   accord-  ing to law. For the families descended from Solomon, and
>   those  from Nathan, were so intermingled, by substitutions in the
>   place  of those who had died childless, by second marriages and the
>   raising up of seed, that the same persons are justly considered, as
>   in  one respect, belonging to the one of these, and in another respect
>   belonging to others. Hence it is, that both of these accounts being 
>   true, viz. of those who were reputed fathers, and those v>'ho really 
>   were fathers, they come down to Joseph with considerable intri-  cacy,
>   it is true, but with great accuracy. That this, however,  may be made
>   evident, I will state the series of generations. If  (in the genealogy
>   of Matthew,) you reckon the generations from  David through Solomon,
>   Matthan, who begat Jacob the father of  Joseph, is found to be the
>   third from the end. But if, with Luke,  you reckon from Nathan the son
>   of David, in like manner, Melchi,  whose son was Eli, the father of
>   Joseph, will be found to be the  third. As Joseph, then, is our
>   proposed object, we are to show  how it happened that each is recorded
>   as his father ; both Jacob,  as deduced from Solomon, and Eli from
>   Nathan ; also, how it happened that these two, Jacob and Eli, were
>   brothers ; and more-  over, how the fathers of these, Matthan and
>   Melchi, being of  different families, are proved to be the
>   grandfathers of Joseph.
>
> Matthan and Melchi, having married in succession the same  woman, had
>   children, who were brothers by the same mother, as  the law did not
>   prohibit a widow, whether she became such by  divorce, or by the death
>   of her husband, to marry again. Mat-  than, therefore, who traces his
>   lineage from Solomon, first had  Jacob, by Estha, for this is her name
>   as handed down by tradition.  Matthan dying, and Melchi, who traces
>   his descent from Nathan,  though he was of the same tribe, but of
>   another family, having  as before said, married her, had a son Eli.
>   Thus, then, we shall  find the two of different families, Jacob and
>   Eli, brothers by the  same mother. Of these, the one Jacob, on the
>   death of his bro-  ther, marrying his widow, became the father of a
>   third, viz. Jo-  seph ; his son both by nature and calculation.
>   Wherefore, it is  written, Jacob begat Joseph. But according to the
>   lav/, he was  the son of Eli, for Jacob being his brother, raised up
>   seed to him.  Wherefore, the genealogy traced also through him, will
>   not be  rendered void, which, according to Matthew, is given thus — "
>   but  Jacob begat Joseph." But Luke, on the other hand, says, " who was
>   the son, as was supposed, (for this he also adds,) the son of Joseph, 
>   the son of Eli, the son of Melchi." For it was not possible to ex- 
>   press the legal genealogy more distinctly, so that he entirely omits 
>   the expression, " he begat,''^ in a generation like this, until the
>   end ;  having traced it back as far as Adam, " who was the son of
>   God,"  he resolves the whole series by referring back to God. Neither 
>   is this incapable of proof, nor is it an idle conjecture. For the re- 
>   latives of our Lord, according to the flesh, whether to display  their
>   own illustrious origin, or simply to show the fact, but at any  rate
>   adhering strictly to the truth, have also handed down the  following
>   accounts : That robbers of Idumea, attacking Ascalon,  a city of
>   Palestine, led Antipater away captive together with  other booty, from
>   the temple of Apollo, which was built close to the  walls. He was the
>   son of one Herod, a minister of the temple.  The priest, however, not
>   being able to pay the ransom for his son,  Antipater was trained up in
>   the practices of the Idumeans, and  afterwards in great favour with
>   Hyrcanus the high priest of Ju-  dea. He was subsequently sent by
>   Hyrcanus on an embassy to  Pompey, and having restored the kingdom to
>   him, which had  been invaded by Aristobulus, the brother of the
>   latter, Antipater  himself had the good fortune to be nominated the
>   procurator of  Palestine. Antipater, however, having been
>   treacherously slain, by  those who envied his good fortune, was
>   succeeded by his son Herod.  He was afterwards, by a decree of the
>   senate, appointed king of  the Jews, under Antony and Augustus. His
>   sons were Herod and  the other tetrarchs. These accounts of the Jews
>   also coincide  with those of the Greeks. But, as the genealogies of
>   the Hebrews  had been regularly kept in the archives until then, and
>   also of  those who referred back as far as the ancient proselytes ; as
>   for  mstance, to Achior the Ammonite, and Ruth the Moabitess, and  to
>   those that were intermixed with the Israelites at their depar-  ture
>   from Egypt ; and as the hneage of the Israelites contributed  nothing
>   to Herod's advantage, he was goaded by the conscious-  ness of his
>   ignoble extraction, and committed all these records of  their families
>   to the flames. Thinking that himself might ap-  pear of noble origin,
>   by the fact that no one else would be able  to trace his pedigree by
>   the pubhc records, back to patriarchs or  proselytes, and to those
>   strangers that were called georas.* A  few however of the careful,
>   either remembering the names, or  having it in their power in some
>   other way, by means of copies, to  have private records of their own,
>   gloried in the idea of preserving  the memory of their noble
>   extraction. Of these were the above-  mentioned persons, called
>   desposyni,-!" on account of tlieir afiinity  to the family of our
>   Saviour. These coming from Nazara and  Cochaba, villages of Judea, to
>   the other parts of the world, explained
>   the aforesaid genealogy from the book of daily records, as 
>   faithfully as possible. Whether, then, the matter be thus or other- 
>   wise, as far as I and every impartial judge would say, no one 
>   certainly could discover a more obvious interpretation. And  this,
>   then, may suffice on the subject ; for, although it be not sup- 
>   ported by testimony, we have nothing to advance, either better or 
>   more consistent with truth. The gospel, altogether, states the 
>   truth." At the close of the same epistle, this writer, (Africanus,) 
>   adds the following : " Matthan, whose descent is traced to Solo-  mon,
>   begat Jacob, Matthan dying, Melchi, whose lineage is from  Nathan, by
>   marrying the widow of the former, had Eli. Hence,  Eli and Jacob were
>   brothers by the same mother. Eli dying  childless, Jacob raised up
>   seed to him, having Joseph, according  to nature belonging to himself,
>   but by the law to Eli. Thus, Jo-  seph was the son of both." So far
>   Africanus ; and the lineage of  Joseph thus being traced, Mary, also,
>   at the same time, as far as  can be, is evinced to be of the same
>   tribe, since, by the ^Mosaic  law, intermarriages among different
>   tribes were not permitted.  For the injunction is, to marry one of the
>   same kindred, and the  same family, so that the inheritance may not be
>   transferred from  tribe to tribe. And this may suffice, also, on the
>   present point.

Answer (score 0):

Pére Binet, S.J., [*The Divine Favors Granted to St. Joseph*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6472), ch. 1:

> The Evangelists* would appear to give Joseph two fathers; but the contradiction is only apparent. St. Luke says he was the son of Heli, who, however, died childless; while St. Matthew calls him the son of Jacob, because, according to several commentators, Jacob, brother of Heli, espoused his sister-in-law Esta as the law of Moses commanded, by whom he had Joseph, who was thus the son of Jacob by nature, and the son of Heli according to the law.

<sup>*[Mt. 1:16](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=1&l=16-#x): "**Jacob** begot Joseph the husband of Mary"
[Lk. 3:23](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=3&l=23-#x): "Joseph, who was of **Heli**"</sup>

Cornelius à Lapide, S.J., explains this in detail ([Commentary on Luke](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3842) 3:23):

> *As was supposed, the son of Joseph, which was* (here, and before each of the following names the Arabic puts in “the son”) *of Heli, which was of Mathat*. From this passage Porphyry and Julian the Apostate accused Luke of being incorrect, because Joseph was not the son of Heli, but of Jacob, as S. Matthew says (ch. 1); and because S. Luke gives the other progenitors of Joseph and Heli names entirely different from those given them by S. Matthew.
> Besides, Jesus was not the son of Joseph, but born of the Virgin Mary.
> The solution given by some to this difficulty is that Joseph was by nature the son of Jacob, but by law the son of Heli. By the old law ([Deut. 25:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=5&ch=25&l=5-#x)) a surviving brother had to raise up seed to his dead brother, and the brother who had died childless was held to be the legal father of these sons. Now Jesca, says Euthymius, married Mathat, and by him had Heli, then she married Mathan, and by him had Jacob. Heli died without issue, and his brother Jacob married his wife in accordance with the law, and Joseph was his son by her, being, therefore, ***naturally* the son of Jacob, but *legally* of Heli**. So Justinus, S. Jerome, Eusebius, Nazianzen, and S. Ambrose explain it. But, on the other hand, Heli and Jacob were only uterine brothers, and the law on the subject of raising up seed to a brother only applies to full brothers, sons of the same father; for they alone kept the name and heritage of the father, Besides, the introduction of Jesca is beside the point. For though her sons, Heli and Jacob, be connected through her, yet they would have no connection through Mathat and Mathan and the rest of their ancestors up to David.

Answer (score -3):

[Raymond E. Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_E._Brown) says, in *[An Introduction to the New Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300140169)*, page 236, that while Luke's list may be less classically monarchical than Matthew's, there is little likelihood that either is strictly historical. On this view, there is no mistake and no misunderstanding of Jewish genealogies.  Brown notes that many try to reconcile the two very different genealogies by saying that they are indeed historical, but that Matthew's is the genealogy back through Joseph and Luke's goes back through Mary - in spite of Luke 3:23!

> [Luke 3:23](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Luke&chapter=3&verse=23): And Jesus himself began to be about thirty years of age, being (as was supposed) the son of **Joseph, which was the son of Heli**

[Joachim Jeremias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim_Jeremias), in [Jerusalem](http://khazarzar.skeptik.net/books/jremias2.pdf), page 290, says both gospels give the ancestry of the carpenter Joseph, and both try to show his Davidic origin, noting that ancient and modern attempts to see one as Mary's genealogy have all failed. On page 296, Jeremias reports that the custom of using the names of the twelve patriarchs as personal names did not arise until after the exile, so when *Luke* cites the names of Joseph, Judah, Simeon, and Levi as descendants six to nine, it is an anachronism that proves at least that the pre-exilic portion of Luke's genealogy has no historical value.

On the evidence of Raymond Brown, Joachim Jeremias and many others, the genealogies in both *Matthew* and *Luke* are portrayed as that of Joseph. Therefore it can be said that in *Matthew*, Joseph's father was Jacob, while in *Luke* his father was Heli. Brown says (page 176) that Matthew's Joseph is shaped in the image of the patriarch Joseph, another son of Jacob, because both interpret dreams and save the family by going to Egypt. There are many parallels between Matthew's flight to Egypt and the Old Testament sojourn in Egypt.

Answer (score -4):

Genealogies presented in Matthew and Luke can be seen as being in contradiction when you believe that Greek was the original language of the Gospels. Such contradiction doesn't exist in Aramaic manuscripts and it can be showed that contradictions in Greek manuscripts come from poor translating from Aramaic ones.

Recomennded scholarly reading:

1. ["Use of *0rbg* in Classical and Contemporary Aramaic Thought"](http://www.peshitta.org/bethgazza/Gabra.htm) by Paul David Younan.
2. [Exploding the Myth of a Flawed Genealogy in Matthew](http://www.peshitta.org/bethgazza/Myth) by Andrew Gabriel Roth.

Comment: And then on the other hand, there is a way to read the genealogies in Greek without any contradiction whatsoever, as many expositors have done.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81, of course, you don't need to stick up with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor